# When to use NLineInputFormat in Hadoop Map-Reduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a **Text based** input file of size around **25 GB**. And in that file one single record consists of **4** lines. And the processing for every *record* is the same. But inside every record,each of the four lines are processed differently.

I'm new to Hadoop so I wanted a guidance that whether to use `NLineInputFormat` in this situation or use the default `TextInputFormat` ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the text file in the following format :

```
2015-8-02
error2014 blahblahblahblah
2015-8-02
blahblahbalh error2014
```

---

You could use [NLineInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.3-alpha/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/NLineInputFormat.html).

With `NLineInputFormat` functionality, you can specify exactly how many lines should go to a mapper.

In your case you can use to input 4 lines per mapper.

**EDIT**:

Here is an example for using NLineInputFormat:

**Mapper Class:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MapperNLine extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        context.write(key, value);
    }

}
```

**Driver class:**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.NLineInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class Driver extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out
                  .printf("Two parameters are required for DriverNLineInputFormat- <input dir> <output dir>\n");
            return -1;
        }

        Job job = new Job(getConf());
        job.setJobName("NLineInputFormat example");
        job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);
        NLineInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        job.getConfiguration().setInt("mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap", 4);

        LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(MapperNLine.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return success ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new Driver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```